# Possible ways to calculate X = A - inv(B) * Y * inv(B) and X = Y + A' * inv(B) * A

Tags: matrix, inversion

I have two problems. I have to calculate two equations:

X = A - inv(B) * Y * inv(B)

and

X = Y + A' * inv(B) * A

where, A, B and Y are known p*p matrices (p can be small or large, depends the situation). Matrices are quite dense, without any structure (except B being non-singular of course).

Is it possible to solve X in those equations without inverting the matrix B? I have to calculate these equations n times, n being hundreds or thousands, and all the matrices change over time.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I guess no for the general case, although my algebra fu could be better. If you give more context (what do you need X for? are there relations between A and B?) there might still be something in it.

Comment: Math related but not programming related. There are plenty of Math Q&A sites out there folks, sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memo-ize inv(B), i.e. only invert B when it changes, and keep the inverse around.

If changes to B are small, possibly you could use a delta-approximation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can express your updates to your matrix B in the following terms:

```
Bnew = B + u*s*v
```

then you can express an update to `inv(B)` explicitly using the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury formula:

```
inv(B + u*s*v) = inv(B) - inv(B)*u*inv(s + v*inv(B)*u)*v*inv(B)
```

If u and v are vectors (column and row, respectively) and s is scalar, then this expression simplifies:

```
inv(B + u*s*v) = inv(B) - inv(B)*u*v*inv(B)/(s + v*inv(B)*u)
```

You would only have to calculate `inv(B)` once and then update it when it changes with no additional inversions.

It may be preferable not to calculate the full inverse, just simple "matrix divisions" on y and (ynew - y) or a and (anew - a) depending on the size of "n" with respect to "p" in your problem.